# Printing in Landscape mode vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i had manage to print the contents of my datagrid view, but it doesnt fit in portrait mode. i guess printing it in landscape mode will do.

**i have this code for my dataset to fill the datagridview.**

```
Private Sub print_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM TBLusers"
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter(query, CN)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    CN.Open()

    DA.Fill(DS, "Users")
    CN.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables("Users")
    'DataGridView1.DataMember = "Users"


End Sub
```

**here is the function for printing i guess? i got it from a tutorial.**

```
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim dataGridViewImage As New Bitmap(Me.DataGridView1.Width, Me.DataGridView1.Height)
    DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(dataGridViewImage, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.DataGridView1.Width, Me.DataGridView1.Height))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(dataGridViewImage, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

**here is the print preview.**

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    PrintPreviewDialog2.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreviewDialog2.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1
    PrintPreviewDialog2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

**and the print...**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub
```

**i tried

PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True**

but it doesnt seems to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're setting the `DefaultPage` setting for the printer.
Try to set it for the document itself:

```
PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
PrintDocument1.Print()
```